# Is it possible to skip nodes in an XML file in Excel VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing

I'm quite new to all this XML and VBA. I'm honestly doing everything based on my knowledge of oop, but the current project I am working on requires to be done in VBA.
I've searched everywhere but I can't find and can't think of any practical way to do what I must do right now, so I am asking for everyone's knowledge in here for help if it's possible.

So basically I have an XML file that is something like this:

```
<a name="something" >
   <b name="something">
      <c>
         <d>number1</d>
         <e>number2</e>
         <f>
            <g>number3</g>
            <h>number4</h>
         </f>
       </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

My problem is that I need to generate the contents of the XML in an Excel worksheet. I do know how to do that, however, what I end up with is something like:

> something
>   something
>   *number1 number2 number3 number4*
>   number1
>   number2
>   *number3 number4*
>   number3
>   number4

What I want is to somehow get rid of the lines in italics.

I'm using recursion within sub procedures because that's how it is required. However, when I check for child nodes and for the node value to be printed, I end up with all the child nodes and their values of the nodes that do not have a particular value themselves.

I know I could skip over the nodes manually using the baseName but this is not what I'm looking for. If it's possible to make a function of it's own or something more general that could apply to any cases of this happening, would be nice.

Thank you for the help!

EDIT: (The code I have for now)

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Clear

    Dim point As IXMLDOMSelection

    Filename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    XDoc.Load (Filename)

    Set point = XDoc.SelectNodes("/*")
    Call ProcessChildNodes(point(0))
End Sub


Sub PrintNodeValue(Node As IXMLDOMNode)
    If (Node.Attributes.Length = 0) Then
        Row = Row + 1
        mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 1).Value = Node.Text
    End If
End Sub


Sub PrintAttributesValue(Node As IXMLDOMNode)
    If (Node.Attributes.Length <> 0) Then
        Row = Row + 1
        For j = Node.Attributes.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
            strng = Node.Attributes.Length
            mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, strng - j).Value = Node.Attributes(j).Text
        Next
    End If
End Sub


Sub ProcessChildNodes(Node As IXMLDOMNode) 
    If (Node.HasChildNodes) Then
        For m = 0 To Node.ChildNodes.Length - 1
            If Node.ChildNodes(m).NodeType <> NODE_TEXT Then
                Call PrintNodeValue(Node.ChildNodes(m))
                Call PrintAttributesValue(Node.ChildNodes(m))
                Call ProcessChildNodes(Node.ChildNodes(m))
            End If
        Next
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's hard to say something if we don't see the code. Please [edit] your question and add your VBA code or better a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the code I have for now. Thank you so much for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to ignore the nodes that have

- no text entry
- and no attribute

in your example `<c>` and `<f>`.

---

The only trick I found is to process the XML directly.
So we first search for a unique parameter that only node `<c>` and `<f>` have but no other node. Therefore I found this rules:

1. The node must not have an attribute
2. The node must be followed directly by another node (no text)

That means after `<c>` and `<f>` there is directly another tag beginning with `<`.

#### The Theory

1. If we have a look at the XML code of node `<c>` which we get with `Node.xml` it looks like:

   ```
   <c>
       <d>number1</d>
       <e>number2</e>
       <f>
           <g>number3</g>
           <h>number4</h>
       </f>
   </c>
   ```
2. to make it easier to process we flatten out the line breaks, tabs and spaces, so we end up here:

   ```
   <c><d>number1</d><e>number2</e><f><g>number3</g><h>number4</h></f></c>
   ```
3. Now we just need to check if the first node tag `<c>` is **directly** followed by another tag beginning with `<`. Therefore we find the first `>` and see if it is followed by `<`. If this is true then the node can be omitted because it has no attribute nor has it a text.

#### Let's Start Coding

1. We do everything in the `PrintNodeValue` procedure and start with declaring a variable and getting the raw XML code of the actually processed node:

   ```vb
   Dim xml as String
   xml = Node.xml
   ```
2. We flatten that `xml` and remove all line breaks, tabs and spaces

   ```vb
   xml = Replace(xml, vbCrLf, vbNullString)
   xml = Replace(xml, vbTab, vbNullString)
   xml = Replace(xml, " ", vbNullString)
   ```

   `xml` is now `<c><d>number1</d><e>number2</e><f><g>number3</g><h>number4</h></f></c>`
3. We remove the first tag

   ```vb
   xml = Right(xml, Len(xml) - InStr(1, xml, ">"))
   ```

   and see if our 2 rules (no attribute and followed by another tag directly apply)

   ```vb
   If (Node.Attributes.Length = 0) And Left(xml, 1) <> "<" Then
   ```

#### So we end up with …

```vb
Sub PrintNodeValue(Node As IXMLDOMNode)
    Dim xml As String
    xml = Node.xml                                  'get raw xml
    xml = Replace(xml, vbCrLf, vbNullString)        'strip off line breaks
    xml = Replace(xml, vbTab, vbNullString)         'strip off tabs
    xml = Replace(xml, " ", vbNullString)           'strip off spaces
    xml = Right(xml, Len(xml) - InStr(1, xml, ">")) 'strip off first tag

    If (Node.Attributes.Length = 0) And Left(xml, 1) <> "<" Then 'check our 2 rules
        iRow = iRow + 1
        mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Node.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

which produces …

> something
>   something
>   number1
>   number2
>   number3
>   number4

*Note that you might need to change `vbCrLf` to `vbCr` or `vbLf` depending from which system eg. Windows, Linux or Mac the XML file originally came from (they use different line breaks). To be safe you also can remove all 3.*

```vb
xml = Replace(xml, vbCrLf, vbNullString)
xml = Replace(xml, vbCr, vbNullString)
xml = Replace(xml, vbLf, vbNullString)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a useful, clear and detailed answer!

Comment: Is there no way to do this using xpath? I have run into a similar situation